# Watching for array additions/deletions in Vue

Tags: vue.js

When watching an array in Vue like this:

```js
watch: {
  myarray(val) {
    // react to additions or deletions on myarray
  },
},
```

and adding or removing items on that array like this:

```js
this.myarray.splice(this.myarray.findIndex((d) => d.id === myId), 1);
this.myarray.push({name: 'New Item'});
```

how do I watch for these additions or deletions on the array. Two ways I could do this:

- Use v-for to generate (renderless) components and use the created()/beforeDestroy() hooks of this component.
- Compare the old to the new version of the array and find differences (by iterating over the whole array)

But both methods would add a performance overhead to my application (There are up to a hundred thousand elements in this array).
Is there any way the watch callback can pass me a list of additions or deletions.

The `(value, mutation)` callback described here: https://optimizely.github.io/vuejs.org/api/instance-methods.html would be exactly what I need. Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: Uses `Vue.set(...)` or `vm.$set(...)` for adding one element, uses `Vue.delete(...)` or `vm.$delete(...)` to delete one element.

Comment: How are you adding and deleting the elements in that array? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and provide the code so your situation becomes understandable.

Comment: Hi, is there a way for you to grab the index of the element you are deleting and then you can do this
data() {
  return {
    indexOfObjectDeleted: 0,
  }

this.indexOfObjectDeleted = ......;

watch: {
  myarray(newValOfArray, oldValueOfArray) {
    const valueOfObjectDeleted = oldValueOfArray[this.indexOfObjectDeleted]
  },
},

Comment: Unfortunately not, the array is a prop coming from a parent component, I don't even know if anything was deleted or added on the array.

Comment: @crs, you can pass props such `isArrayDeleted`, `indexOfArrayDeleted`etc. from the parent component.

Comment: Why do you need to know specifically which elements were added/deleted? Maybe there's a better solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best method I came up with so far would be overwriting the push and splice methods of the array. I don't really like this solution though, as it doesn't use Vue's built-in reactivity which does basically the same I am doing here:

```js
created() {
  this.myarray.push = (...args) => {
    //do something with args
    return Array.prototype.push.apply(this.myarray, args);
  };
  this.myarray.splice = (...args) => {
    //do something with args
    return Array.prototype.splice.apply(this.myarray, args);
  };
  //any more array methods you want to intercept
},
```

Alternatively, and if you don't need existing code using `push()` and `splice()` to be compatible with this, you could of course define new functions such as `push2()` and `splice2()` to avoid overwriting the native functions.

Or you could define such functions on the component itself to act as setter for the array.

Note that when using the above snippet you loose Vues own reactivity on that array. To keep both you would have to do:

```js
created() {
  const originalPush = this.myarray.push;
  const originalSplice = this.myarray.splice;
  this.myarray.push = (...args) => {
    //do something with args
    return originalPush.apply(this.myarray, args);
  };
  this.myarray.splice = (...args) => {
    //do something with args
    return originalSplice.apply(this.myarray, args);
  };
  //any more array methods you want to intercept
},
```